# Switch on enum with Flags

Tags: c#, enums, switch-statement

I have the following enum

```
[Flags]
public enum Anchor
{
    None = 1,
    Top = 2, Bottom = 4,
    Left = 8, Right = 16
}
```

I need to test every possible combination of Top, Bottom, Left and Right but declaring all those combinations in a switch is awful.

```
switch (anchor)
{
    case Anchor.Left:
        Thing1();
        break;

    case Anchor.Top:
        Thing2();
        break;

    case Anchor.Left | Anchor.Top:
        Thing3();
        break;
}
```

This question is not a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3846979/bitwise-flags-and-switch-statement) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1040731/switch-on-enum-with-flags-attribute-without-declaring-every-possible-combinati). I've tried both solutions and neither works for me because if my enum is, say `Anchor.Left | Anchor.Top`, `Thing1()` and `Thing2()` would be called whereas I need `Thing3()` to be called.

Comment: Just as an aside, it's unusual to have `None` in an enum defined to be anything other than 0 - in this case would you behave differently to `case Anchor.Left | Anchor.None:` to `case Anchor.Left:`?

Comment: So basicially you want to make compiler guess what should be called. It's not possible, if you wan't completely different reactions for states combinations, you need to specify it explicit.

Comment: @RowlandShaw Yes I forgot to mention that. If the given enum has `Anchor.None` set in it, all other flags should be ignored and a case for `None` should be used. It's probably not part of my problem.

Comment: How is anchor variable being set/initialized? If anchor = Anchor.Left | Anchor.Top; then Thing3() is invoked as expected.

Comment: @GiorgosBetsos That is true, but I need cases for all 24 combinations of `Top`, `Bottom`, `Left` and `Right` (`None` ignored). Like I said previously, declaring all those in the switch is awful.

Comment: If any combination that has `None` in it is going to be ignored, I'd put the entire `switch` statement into an `if` statement that will ignore that. Make it explicit so that your code will self-document. But a comment would also be helpful there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declare all these combinations in a switch. (as you started)

Its clear, understandable, maintainable.

Not awful. (Feels just a bit stupid to key it in)

After all, you have these distict cases, so a switch is the perfect construction.

Comment: Spans,

Unlike DrKoch, I'll give you an answer that is not "Jerk like".  The best solution to your answer is to use "if" blocks for each flag your testing.  Using a 'switch' is for when you want to target specific combinations of your flags.  For example:
if (anchor.HasFlag(Anchor.Left)) {
  Thing1();
}
if (anchor.HasFlag(Anchor.Top)) {
  Thing2();
}, ect, ect.


Notice I did not use an 'if else' as that would preclude your other flags.  It is not as elegant as a "switch" statement, but it is the only solution to what your trying to achieve.

Take care and God bless.

Comment: @rashadrivera your answer is the best by far. I have this situation with an enum with 15 elements. Going case by case would be so tedious and unmaintainable.